# 2 days later 'Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)

Tags: python

I have a pretty simple python program to send weight data from a serial port to an http server.
get the data from serial port and figure out the URL, then requests.get(url).
it runs very well at start, but may be one or 2 days later, got

'Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)

The code run no problem and get the correct result. But 1 or 2 days later, it can not reach the server and log show:
'Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)

Then, after I restart the server, the issue disappear and work properly, 1-2 days later, issue again. is this server side issue?

The code is:

import logging.handlers

```
LOG_FILE = 'console.log'
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=1024 * 1024, backupCount=5)  # 实例化handler
fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(name)s - %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger('console')
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)




import requests
upload_url="http://localhost:8888/test"
while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(buffer)
            if not data:
                break
            requests.get(upload_url, {"name": "weight", "value": get_weight})
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(e)
```

Comment: depending on what you're using for logging it may be that your remote logging is failing to connect, can we see the rest of the file?

Comment: the log is local file log, not remote log.

Comment: Again, every time this issue happen, when I restart the server, it can work again. 1-2 days later, issue again. is this the problem of server?  The server is run at same machine.

Comment: Are you sure that Firewall or iptables is down?

Comment: the client and server run at same machine, it can run ok at first, only after 1-2 days the issue happen, then restart the server service(not restart HW server, only restart the http server), it works ok.